# background-position property unable to center the image

Tags: html, css, background-image

The following code is unable to place the image at the center of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url("../images/dandelion.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

This is what I am getting.

[image]

Comment: make more specific of your question.

Comment: I want to center the image

Comment: And this is what you are getting. The height of the body is not what you would expect and it's what is being used to align the image. Set a height for your body and you should see what I mean.

Comment: You want to center image horizontally and vertically, correct? if you inspect your body element you will see that it is only a certain amount of pixels in height. This is because the body doesn't automatically fill your entire browser window, it only does so for the width.

Comment: @GillesC that was quick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `body` is only as tall as the things inside it, so its actually centering correctly.

To get the result you want, you need to either make the actual page longer by adding things to it, or this to work around:

```
html,body{ height:100%; }
```

Note that you need to have html in there too because percentage height is relative to its parent (`<html>` is a parent of `<body>` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

u may want to try something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zehyre8/2/)

```css
body{
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/InDshke.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center -25%;
  background-size: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhrmf3su/)** (jsFiddle).

You need to reset default properties and give these some styles as your containers such as `<html>` and `<body>` are adjusted according to the content inside it (in this case the image).

Apply these styles:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give html and body height 100% and background position 50% 50% or center center.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/InDshke.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```